# AngularJS / PHP － ng-repeat with getting array from php shows nothing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I’m having some trouble when using ng-repeat.

At first, I get a JSON object from database (**read.php**). And convert it into a javascript array object

```
var as = JSON.parse(data);
$scope.datadata = as;
```

I can get response `$scope.datadata` in console finely, but get nothing in browser. So I used a test array `$scope.Picture_set`, and it correctly showed up in browser. What can I do to my code to show the database items through `ng-repeat`?

[image: pic]

## read.php

```
<?php

require 'lib.php';
$object = new CRUD();
$picturetb = $object->Read();

if (count($picturetb) > 0) {
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($picturetb as $key=>$picture) {
        $arr[] = array('key' => $key, 'name' => $picture['Picture_Name']);
    }     
}
echo json_encode($arr); 

?>
```

## html

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="drawbackController" class="container-fluid">    
      <div class="sidenav">                
          <table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>No. </th>
                      <th>PictureName</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <!-- fail -->
                  <tr ng-repeat="d in datadata">

                  <!-- success -->
                  <!-- <tr ng-repeat="d in Picture_set"> -->
                      <td> {{ d.key }} </td>
                      <td><a> {{ d.name }} </a></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>

          <br>
          <div class="addPicture" id="addPicture"></div>
      </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

## JS.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
mainApp.controller('drawbackController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.datadata =[];

    // READ records
    $scope.readRecords = function () {
        $.get("ajax/read.php", {}, function (data, status) {

            console.log(data);
            var as = JSON.parse(data);
            $scope.datadata = as;

            console.log($scope.Picture_set);
            console.log($scope.datadata);

            $(".addPicture").html($scope.datadata);
        });
    }
    $scope.readRecords();

    // a test array
    $scope.Picture_set = [
        { 'name': 'picture1' },
        { 'name': 'picture2' },
        { 'name': 'picture3' },
        { 'name': 'picture4' },
        { 'name': 'picture5' }
    ];

});
```

Comment: It is working fine for me, Can you create a fiddle and reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery's `$.get` instead of AngularJS's `$http.get`.
As a consequence, your `$scope` is not aware of the changes in the `$.get` callback.
You can..

- use `$http.get` and the `$scope` will detect changes automatically
- in your current code, wrap the changes in the `$scope.apply()` function

You can [read](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide:-When-to-use-$scope.$apply()f) about `$scope.apply`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem. I tried  `$scope.$apply(function () {   });` this, and it work.